# CSS HTML form "file" customize

Tags: html, css

Can someone teach me or give me a link for my problem?

I wanted to customize my form "file" --> for uploading.
How can I customize it?

```
.classfile {
css codes....
}

<input type="file" name="name" class="classfile" />
```

If I do that way the text box and button of form will be affected. What is the other way to customize that?

Comment: not getting you can plz explain more

Comment: Are you looking for the CSS selector `input[type="file"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't style a

```
<input type="file">
```

Just with CSS. Take a look here for a great trick : http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: You can't and you shouldn't. This is done purposely, to stop tricking people with this security/privacy critical element.